# Data from api not displaying in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, chart.js

> `'import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
> import { Chart as ChartJS, BarElement } from 'chart.js/auto';
> import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
>
> ChartJS.register(
> BarElement,
> );
>
> const BarChart = () => {
> const [chart, setChart] = useState({});
> const [coins, setCoins] = useState([]);
>
> const coinIds = ['bitcoin', 'ethereum', 'cardano'];
>
> const apiKey = '6303b0c3-fa99-45cc-9b0c-cca70a6f0398';
>
> useEffect(() => {
> const fetchCoins = async () => {
> const coinPromises = coinIds.map((id) => {
> return fetch(`https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=${id}`, {
> headers: {
> 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
> 'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': `${apiKey}`,
> },
> })
> .then((response) => {
> if (response.ok) {
> return response.json().then((json) => {
> return json.data[id].quote.USD;
> });
> else {
> throw new Error('Failed to fetch coin data');
> }
> })
> .catch((error) => {
> console.log(error);
> return null;
> });
> });
>
> try {
> const coinsData = await Promise.all(coinPromises);
> setCoins(coinsData.filter((coin) => coin !== null));
> catch (error) {
> console.log(error);
> }
> };
>
> fetchCoins();
> [apiKey, coinIds]);
>
> const data = {
> labels: coins.map((coin) => coin.name),
> datasets: [
> {
> label: 'Market Cap',
> data: coins.map((coin) => coin.market_cap),
> backgroundColor: [
> 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
> 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
> 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
> 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
> 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
> 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
> ],
> borderColor: [
> 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
> 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
> 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
> 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
> 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
> 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
> ],
> borderWidth: 1,
> },
> ],
> };
>
> const options = {
> maintainAspectRatio: false,
> scales: {},
> legend: {
> labels: {
> fontSize: 25,
> },
> },
> };
>
> return (
>
>
>
> );
> };'
>
> export default BarChart;`

[Screenshot of inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2t21.png)

this is my code for my barchart.js file, but the chart is showing, however the data isnt displaying and i have an infinite loop of errors which just increase on inspect. I tried using another api but same issue

Comment: The console seems to show that `fetch` on your api link failed (because of CORS). Most likely you can't access the data provided by that API from another server without registering and being provided with an API key

Comment: I have an API key, where would I use it then to grab the data? sorry I'm only a first-year developer

Comment: btw be careful when you are posting API keys. i don't know if you edited it already or anything. I'm saying in case you didn't

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Quick-Start-Guide) of the service you are using, I saw this `Note: Making HTTP requests on the client side with Javascript is currently prohibited through CORS configuration....` As far as I understand it, you have to set up your own server side script (node, php, etc) that accesses the api in a similar way to a curl command and then you would retrieve the data in your frontend app from that server script of yours.